# Does TypeScript JSDoc-style typing have full power of regular types?

Tags: typescript, types

TypeScript is said to be ["turing complete"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833). Is the JSDoc-style typing as feature full as regular types? Can we do mapped types, conditional types, keyof, etc, and all the things of regular types?

Just curious, because I'd like to declare types for JS files that implement class-factory mixins and that define define functions that accepts objects and return classes generated from the object definition. The generated classes should have protected and private members, and the mixins should return classes with protected/private members.

I'd like to type these things without having to convert to `.ts` files, just keep the JS code as is.

Is it possible with JSDoc comments, to type such meta things like generated classes from object literal definitions and class-factory mixins, etc?

Comment: This seems to conflate two different concepts. Turing completeness doesn't imply the expressiveness described in the second paragraph, nor vice versa. Are you asking if JS Doc in TS can express all the same concepts as regular type declarations/annotations, or if it is a turing complete system?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I'm asking the former regarding whether JSDoc in TS can express all the same concepts as regular type declarations/annotations. Can it?

Answer (score 1):

Not all types expressible in TypeScript can be represented in JSDoc. Example:

```
/**
 * @typedef Parameters
 * A tuple of the types of the parameters of a function.
 * @template T
 * @type {(T extends (...args: infer U) => * ? U : never)}
 */
```

Trying to use this type causes the TypeScript service to think that `Paramaters<T> = any`. This means that conditional types are not supported.

In general, you can figure out whether a type is supported in JSDoc by writing it and seeing whether the service gives up and just says it's `any`.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll resort to `.d.ts` files for describing my `.js` files. It would be nice to do it all in one `.js` file though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add comment, but Ruby's answer is now outdated. You could do something like

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef Parameters
 * A tuple of the types of the parameters of a function.
 * @type {(T extends (...args: infer U) => * ? U : never)}
 */
/** @type {Parameters<(a: string) => void>} */
const x; // has type [a: string]
```

Comment: Last time I tried that, it didn't work in `.ts` files, only `.js` files. Have they updated TypeScript so that this works in TypeScript (not JavaScript) code? EDIT: Nope, this doesn't work in _TypeScript_ code. Playground shows `any` despite the variable having a type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCm4DeA7ArgWwEaIE4C+4IwAUADaLTgBmZZt4AvOAEQCMATAMxtA . I wish it did though!

Comment: If you want this to work with TypeScript, apparently you'd need to define the type in TypeScript as well (not just in JSDoc)?

Comment: I wish _something_ worked, but no matter what, TypeScript just completely ignores the JSDoc type in .ts files. For example, it does not complain about this: https://tsplay.dev/w2Pojm